# How to pick same colors for same userid

Tags: java, hash, consistent-hashing, string-hashing

I have a library in which a String userid is passed so basis on that String userid, I need to pick either one of these three colors only.

```
RED
BLUE
PINK
```

Let's say if String userid is `12345` then for example it can pick `RED` so next time if same userid `12345` is passed then it should pick same RED colors only.
Another example if String userid is `98765`, then in this case it can pick `BLUE` so next time if same user id `98765` is passed, then it should pick same `BLUE` colors only.

Idea is for same userid, it should pick same colors always. It should not be for same userid it picks one colors first time and then second time it picks some other colors.

What kind of hashing techniques I can use on userid here so that I can pick same colors always for same userid?

```
public enum Colors {
    RED, BLUE, PINK;        


    private String pickColor(String userid) {


    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `hashCode()`?

Comment: So how will I decide for this hashCode pick this color? And then for same hashCode pick same color again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
int userColor = userName.hashCode() % numberOfColors;
```

Comment: `hashCode` can return negative values so `userColor` can be -1 as well. How to fix this case?

Answer (score 1):

`userName.hashCode() % Colors.values().length()` would do the trick. But you might have to change your enum so that

```
public enum Colors {
    RED (0),
    BLUE (1),
    PINK(2);

/* write method to find enum by value */
}
```

Comment: for some userid, this value `userName.hashCode() % Colors.values().length()` is coming as -1 then what should I do?